# Is it normal for one socket connection consuming two tcp ports?

Tags: swift, sockets, tcp, socket.io, port

I use swift version of Socket.IO and there is only one connection handled by a singleton in an app that I am working.

But in the inspector, it says two tcp ports(49209, 49210) are being used constantly. Is this normal behind the scenes?

[image]

Comment: Time past ago , i was made a project with socket.io and i noticed when the first socket is connected always is giving two connections ... i never found the reason ... , can you try to connect more than one to see if it same behavior ?

Comment: I believe its normal , one port for sending data and the other one for receiving.

Comment: as far a is now this is an full duplex connection so , teorically is no need two connections right?

Comment: @M.Othman It is not normal. TCP is a full-duplex protocol.

Comment: Yes my bad , maybe if you looked at the socket client implementation you may look for things like cfstreamcreatpairwithsockettohost function .

Comment: @M.Othman I use `.forcePolling(true)` in the config and cfstreamcreatpairwithsockettohost not called  when forcePolling is true

Comment: @JoaquinJavi Yes, it's the same behavior. I tried 2 and 3 connections all using the forcePolling config, and the tcp ports number doubles. I suppose it has something to do with the forcePolling option

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a browsers behaviour. Modern browsers open always two (or more) connections in order to speed up loading of ressources through parallelisation.

Comment: Thanks for your response!!! It would be nice if you provide some further explanation, like point to the exact number lines of code or some document in either the [socket.io](http://socket.io/) javascript version or the swift version.